# Unable to scrape multiple room names with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have written code to scrape the hotel name (and eventually price) from [The Hilton](https://www.hilton.com/en/search/hilton-honors/?query=London&arrivalDate=2021-09-20&departureDate=2021-09-30&flexibleDates=false&numRooms=1&numAdults=1&numChildren=0&room1ChildAges=&room1).

I have used the class name to select the HTML block which represents where the hotel information is stored, and then used the XPATH to try and scrape the name of the hotel. However, it only outputs the name of the hotel specific to that XPATH, instead of all hotel names on that page. Is this XPATH specific to this hotel, or is there a different way to take all hotel names on that page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = 'https://www.hilton.com/en/search/hilton-honors/?query=London&arrivalDate=2021-09-20&departureDate=2021-09-30&flexibleDates=false&numRooms=1&numAdults=1&numChildren=0&room1ChildAges=&room1'

    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\conor\\Desktop\\diss\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)


working = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('flex.flex-wrap.py-4.border-border.border-b')
for work in working:
    name = work.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hotel-LONCOCI"]').text
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the XPATH contained an ID pertaining to each specific hotel, and thus would only output the one from the XPATH I used.

The HTML block containing the hotel name includes an element in the class name called 'leading-snug'. The following adjustment to the code makes it work.

```
name = work.find_element_by_class_name('leading-snug').text
```

Although, it seems the scraping only works once the site's cookies preferences page is closed.